# How to bypass required fields when asp button and html text both present

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

In my case i have both ASP button and html text field which is required and two buttons.
Like this

```
<input type='text' runat='server' id='textfield' required/>
<asp:Button Text='submit' runat='server' onClick='clickEvent' id='submitButton'/>

<asp:button text='export' runat='server' onClick='exportEvent' id='exportButton'/>
```

Here when

> i click submitButon and textfield empty then it triggers validation
>   and its good.

But when

> i click exportButton that textfield triggers which is unwanted.

**Notes:**

*1) i have tried EnableClientScript="False" and ValidateRequestMode='disabled' both of them didn't work*

*2) tried giving validation group in exportbutton didn't work and i couldn't apply that on pure html field*

Comment: Use `ValidationGroup`

Answer (score 2):

ASP Button has UseSubmitBehavior property, you can set that to false to bypass submit validations for the required button like below

```
<asp:button text='export' runat='server' onClick='exportEvent' id='exportButton' UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>
```

Comment: tried this it went good but in backend 

 `System.InvalidOperationException:'RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render()' `

This error appears.

Comment: Hi @parthrajpanchal can you show your exportEvent code?if really required  at the page level, there is an option to disable event validation by setting EnableEventValidation="false"

Comment: `Response.Charset = "";
string FileName = "Learning" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"; Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
learningListTable.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
learningListTable.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true; learningListTable.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
Response.End();`